# Why copy pointer into variable and read again?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am reading attach_pid function in linux kernel.
Its code is like following:

```
{
    struct pid_link *link;

    link = &task->pids[type];
    link->pid = pid;
    hlist_add_head_rcu(&link->node, &pid->tasks[type]);
}
```

I do not understand why it does not set pointer directly like this: task->pids[type]->pid = pid.
Why it copy task->pids into link variable and read link variable again?
I found many code that copy pointer into a variable and read indirectly.

Does it have synchronous problem or is it good for code reading?

Answer (score 1):

Probably just save us from dereferencing `&task->pids[type]` again latter when calling hlist_add_head_rcu(). But smart compilers should be able to do this by itself.